# Inverse trigonometric function of trigonometric function

Tags: trigonometry, inverse-function

This is a simple question.

We know that

$\sin( arcsin(2\pi) ) = 2\pi$

Because $arcsin$ is the inverse function of $sin$

So logically, the following should be true as well, since $sin$ is the inverse of $arcsin$

$\arcsin( sin(2\pi) ) = 2\pi$

but it actually equals $0$. Why so?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, $\arcsin$ is *not* the inverse of the sine function. Rather, it is the inverse of the restriction of that function to $\left[-\frac\pi2,\frac\pi2\right]$. And the domain of $\arcsin$ is $[-1,1]\left(=\sin\left(\left[-\frac\pi2,\frac\pi2\right]\right)\right)$. So, $\arcsin(2\pi)$ isn't even defined.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I understand what you're saying but then why does my textbook and WolframAlpha give me an answer of $0$. Is that mathematically incorrect?

Comment: $arcsin(sin(2\pi))=arcsin(0)=0$

Comment: Note that my answer was only about the expression $\sin(\arcsin(2\pi))$, which doesn't make sense. As you were told, there is nothing wrong with the expression $\arcsin(\sin(2\pi))$, which is equal to $0$.

Comment: @Divide1918 Yeah you're right. I meant to ask how my textbook and WolframAlpha evaluates $sin(arcsin(2\pi))$ since $2\pi$ is not in the range of $arcsin$. Please excuse me I am quite burnt out...

Answer (score 1):

[image]

$$ y(x)=\sin^{-1} (\sin (x))$$

is a ***triangular wave function*** whose range is $\pm \dfrac{\pi}{2}$ and whose roots $x_k =k \pi$ occur periodically.

When $x= 2 \pi, y=0 $ is the only correct value of ordinate in its graph.

Can be plotted on *Mathematica/ Wolfram-Alpha* etc.

Answer (score 0):

On the unit circle $2\pi=0$ degrees, but the range of $\arcsin{x}$ is $[-\frac{\pi}{2},\frac{\pi}{2}]$.  Therefore, the answer is $0$ because $2\pi$ is outside of the range of $\arcsin{x}$.